# PHP: Why is the use of `global` slower than declaring a variable inside a function?

Tags: php, variables, global

I have been reading PHP manual pages, but I am obviously reading the wrong ones.  I ran a few simple tests to see which means of obtaining a variable was faster: using `global`, declaring the variable inside the function, or using a declared constant.

**Summary:**

1. Declaring the variable (e.g., `$keyspace = 012...;`) was fastest.
2. Using `global` (e.g., `global $keyspace;`).
3. Defining a constant (e.g., `define('keyspace', '01234...');` was slowest.

**Question:** Why is using `global` or `define` slower than declaring a variable in PHP?

**(1) Variable defined outside function, function uses `global`**

```
$keyspace = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
function buildSKU(){
        global $keyspace;
        $sku = '';
        $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; ++$i) {
                $sku .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
        }
        return $sku;
}
```

**(2) Variable defined inside function**

```
function buildSKU(){
        $keyspace = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $sku = '';
        $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; ++$i) {
                $sku .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
        }
        return $sku;
}
```

**(3) Variable defined as a constant**

```
define('keyspace', '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
function buildSKU(){
        $sku = '';
        $max = mb_strlen(keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; ++$i) {
                $sku .= keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
        }
        return $sku;
}
```

**My test bed:**

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);
//Put (1) or (2) here...
for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++){ buildSKU(); }
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "\n\nTime: ".$end."\nMemory:".memory_get_peak_usage(true)."\n\n";
```

Comment: If it's not going to change during a request, then a constant might be the better option.

Comment: Global is considered bad practice. I would much rather pass it the function as an arg, set it as a class property or toss it in a config file and suck it in that way.

Comment: @JonStirling, the results of using a constant were surprisingly slow (though again, not appreciably slow).

Comment: @JBH If you're worrying about that level of efficiency, stop it :P

Comment: A variable declared as `global` should be slightly slower than local variables because it is, in fact, a local variable that stores a reference to a variable from a different scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title is a bit misleading.  A function variable is not being 'declared' over and over, it was declared once when you wrote the function code.  You also focused on an apples to oranges comparison.

With the function variable example, the scope of the variable is entirely different.  A local variable declared inside a function ceases to exist (at least from the scope perspective) once the function completes.  It's also being initialized, unlike the global example where the state of the variable at the start of the function is completely unknown.

You spent a lot of time looking at micro optimization and a meaningless benchmark, when the answer is much simpler.  It is never better to use the `global` keyword to inject a variable into function scope.

You have parameters for doing that which can be passed by reference or value, but you did not evaluate those options, although I have to reiterate that in my opinion you aren't really going to find out anything interesting.

In most languages that create a compiled program, function variables are allocated on the stack.  Once the function completes, that area of memory is popped off the stack and discarded.  PHP however, has a a variable naming and memory allocation scheme that is shared across all variables and objects. You can search for information on 'php zval' and php internals, and find out more about the way variables are allocated, reference counted, and associated with names via symbol tables.

The important point to make here, is that the variable allocation occurs in the same way regardless of the type of variable it is, so any expectation about performance purely of variable allocation syntax is unlikely to provide any meaningful differences.

PHP makes all sorts of decisions in regards to when it needs to make a new zval or simply point multiple symbols at the same one, and that is meant to be transparent to you.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to point out the deficiencies in my understanding of how PHP operates.  I'm not a compiler person, but you didn't know that and it's therefore understandable to receive your admonishment about my limitations in that regard.  I wasn't attempting to optimize anything, but merely attempted to better understand the differences in PHP's operation through the use of tests devised by the best of my limited abilities.  I'm grateful that you have enlightened me such that I can ignore the entire situation, which is an entirely suitable answer.

Comment: Glad it helped, and perhaps pointed you in the direction of some material you might find interesting in regards to php internals.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue with global is the dependency issue, where your entire code base would be depended on that global variable and its existence, as your code grows , it is very hard to keep track and trouble shoot. Even a name change requires you change everywhere in your code.

in your code if key doesn't change maybe you should consider using constant.

Answer (score 0):

Always use local variable unless it is absolutely needed and there is no other way around.